# In Nautilus I have two identical entries in my devices list, why?

Tags: nautilus, fstab

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and have two hard drives, one mounts as `home`, the other as `Data`. Strange thing is that I have the Data drive showing up twice in Nautilus on the devices list. If I click the second one, I get the message:

> Unable to mount Data mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or /media/Data
>
> busy mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda1 is already mounted on
>
> /media/Data

This is my fstab file contents:

> UUID=c0ebf008-2a87-418a-9a74-736931769038 / ext4 defaults 0 1
>
> UUID=c346d075-e2ca-4cb2-b387-e2088ad478a5 swap swap sw 0 0
>
> UUID=ee7513f0-0875-4451-a346-56368896d12b /media/Data ext4 users 0 0

While this is not a HUGE issue, it's annoying, so any suggestions would be welcome...

Thanks, Bill

Edit...
The blkid gave me:

> /dev/sda1: LABEL="Data" UUID="ee7513f0-0875-4451-a346-56368896d12b" TYPE="ext4"
>
> /dev/sdb1: UUID="c0ebf008-2a87-418a-9a74-736931769038" TYPE="ext4"
>
> /dev/sdb5: UUID="c346d075-e2ca-4cb2-b387-e2088ad478a5" TYPE="swap"
>
> /dev/sr1: LABEL="Globe Broadband" TYPE="iso9660"

The df -HT gave me:

> Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/sdb1      ext4      246G   19G  216G   8% /
>
> udev           devtmpfs  2.2G  8.2k  2.2G   1% /dev
>
> tmpfs          tmpfs     846M  881k  845M   1% /run
>
> none           tmpfs     5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
>
> none           tmpfs     2.2G  918k  2.2G   1% /run/shm
>
> /dev/sda1      ext4      1.0T  363G  587G  39% /media/Data

I took a look at the gparted info and everything look normal.

> File system ext4
>
> Size is correct
>
> No flags set
>
> Path and mount is all like regular

Hopefully this tells you all something, because i am baffled ;-)

Thanks, Bill

Comment: Sorry i forgot, Ubuntu 12.04, everything else is all standard.

Comment: Please run Gparted partition editor and just see how the drives listed.Do edit the post with the result.

Comment: Please also add which version of Ubuntu you are using. Also would be interested in seeing the results from `sudo blkid` and `df -HT` if possible. As the [faq#howtoask] recommends, please add new details to your question, **not** as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You could try writing the fstab entry for  Data like this

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ee7513f0-0875-4451-a346-56368896d12b /media/Data ext4 users 0 0
```

very old bug report for reference https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/442130

Comment: Thank you Doug, i tried your solution and the second entry vanished. Wonderful...

Comment: Short and sweet fixes - I love 'em!